# How to render nodes and edges of a 3D network graph

Tags: python, network

I have used the Python API to import a graph of vertices and edges that represent a network graph. Below is a picture of the wireframe (it appears black in some places due to the density of the vertices/edges). Each edge has a vertex at each end (I think this is a requirement in Blender?). Without some additional geometry nodes, most of this time this won't render as it has zero volume.

**Bare vertices and edges:**

[image: vertices and edges]

So far I have managed to visualize the vertices by adding some geometry nodes to instance an icosphere on each vertex, which after adding materials, I can get close to the effect I want on the vertices. (There is some additional logic in there for coloring vertices and randomizing their size and rotation).

**Geometry nodes:**

[image: Geometry nodes]

However, now the original graph edges are not rendering, and I can't see how to get them to show. Do I need a new set of geometry nodes for the edges? I've looked at various solutions that render wireframes, but these all seem to be based on meshes with faces as well. When applied to my model the wireframe effect renders on the instanced icospheres, rather than the edges of my mesh. I am having trouble getting the effect to apply to the edges of the main mesh, rather than the edges of the instanced icospheres.

What do I need to do to make the edges render as lines? A whole new set of geometry nodes? Ideally I would like them to render as faint, slightly glowing lines. Below are some AI generated images that illustrate the effect I would ultimately want to achieve.

Happy to add further information or share code.

**Final goal (AI generated):**

[image: AI generated reference images]

**Edit:**

The edges are now rendering, but I can't get the vertices to render at the same time. how should I be connecting these to the group input and output?
[image: rendered edges]

Comment: "mesh to curve", "curve to mesh", use a circle as a profile (make sure the circle's radius is correct, e.g. if all your points are within a 1m cube, then the radius you want is probably 0.1-1 mm…

You may want to set spline type to bezier, and set handle type to auto for a nicer shape of the curves...

Comment: Thanks @Markus von Broady! I've added an image above with how it's showing now. My issue now is that the vertices are not showing any more. How should I connect these to the input/output to show both?

Comment: Use "Join Geometry" node.

Comment: That's amazing! I think I can do the rest from here, that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing if you don't mind. I want to set random opacity (alpha?) on each of these instanced meshes. How would I do that?